# QSvgWidget behaviour in QTableWidget cell

Tags: python, svg, pyqt4, qtablewidget, stretching

I have QTableWidget and I have populated one column with .svg files with QSvgWidget to show them :

```
for...
    svgWidget = QSvgWidget("C:\mySVG.svg")
    self.ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i, j, svgWidget)
...
```

Other columns are populated with some text, and the problem occurs when I try to use

```
self.ui.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
```

svgWidget is being stretched (I need preserved aspect ratio)...
So, I set max size with `svgWidget.setMaximumSize(svgWidget.sizeHint())` and now
height of every row is set to height of svgWidget in that row, so if there is more text it is being cut, but I can stretch height of any row manually to see text, white space is added in cell with svgWidget, as I expected. My question is why `resizeRowsToContents()` didn't do the job (why white space can't be added automatically?).
Examples would be appreciated, I've googled this out, there is lack of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it like this:

```
self.ui.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(0)
...populating table columns with text and svgWidgets....
self.ui.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(1)
self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorChanged.connect(self.ui.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents)
```

for some reason any other order won't work for me.